# when i use grid in react how can i align items to center 5 of 2

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to align center items in the material-UI grid but the situation must depend on item count. For example, if we have 5 items, 3 items must be side by side in the center and the other 2 items must be in the center. Please check the image.

[image]

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    minHeight: "100vh",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
}));

export default function BlogPostList() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
          <BlogPostCard />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
          <BlogPostCard />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
          <BlogPostCard />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
          <BlogPostCard />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
          <BlogPostCard />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use justifyContent="center":

```
 <div className={classes.root}>
  <Grid container spacing={3} justifyContent="center">
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
      <BlogPostCard />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
      <BlogPostCard />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
      <BlogPostCard />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
      <BlogPostCard />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
      <BlogPostCard />
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</div>
```